# Why is R not applying mutate with a reactive value?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want a Shiny app where z scores are created for certain numeric variables, and then based on user input from the slider, each z score is multiplied by the corresponding user input.  I then want to index (sum) those adjusted z scores and then order the datatable by that index.

I thought I was storing the user inputs in reactive values (x1 and x2) and then calling those values in the construction of the data.frame with adjusted z scores to be fed to renderDataTable.

I am getting this error:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate_") :    no applicable method for 'mutate_'
>   applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets4)

Combine.Data <-  range_read("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EdkRNdmdpCzp4OB-IdRYWhiE3tpDkcOrvKHMxkBfX7w/edit#gid=0", col_names = TRUE)
Combine.Data = as.data.frame(Combine.Data)

# Define UI for application that draws a datatable
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("SSAT App"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for weights 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("Variable1_Weight",
                     "Variable 1 Weight:",
                     min = .01,
                     max = 1.0,
                     value = 0.5),
         sliderInput("Variable2_Weight",
                     "Variable 2 Weight:",
                     min = .01,
                     max = 1.0,
                     value = 0.5)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated table
      mainPanel(
         dataTableOutput("Main.Chart")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  #Generate User Weights Score from user input weights 
  x1 <- reactive({input$Variable1_Weight})
  x2 <- reactive({input$Variable2_Weight})

  DF <- Combine.Data %>% 
  mutate(Forty_zscore = scale(Combine.Data$FORTY, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)) * x1  %>% 
  mutate(Bench_zscore = scale(Combine.Data$BENCH, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)) * x2  %>% 
  mutate(SSAT_Score = Forty_zscore + Bench_zscore)

  #Show the datatable 
   output$Main.Chart = DT::renderDataTable({DF
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And a truncated database: `structure(list(`FIRST NAME`= c("Sean", "Devin", "Amari", "Bryson", 
"Daquan", "Kel", "Wavely", "Cole", "Karl", "Tyjah", "Cameron", 
"Roland", "Matt", "Aaron", "Jeffrey", "Kibwe", "Mark", "Trayevon", 
"Frank", "Arkeem", "Merritt", "Terrell", "Kalil", "Gabriel", 
"Garrett", "Adam", "jaylen", "Justin", "Noan", "Nami", "Sal", 
"Owen", "Richie", "Paul", "Anthony", "Jevon", "Jevon", "Adonus", 
"Alfred", "Emmanuel", "Brandon", "Dominic", "Godwin", "Tyson", 
"Marquise", "Elisha", "Johnny", "Michael", "Dan"),`LAST NAME`= c("Davis", 
"Dixon", "Sims", "Caven", "Wheeler", "Lee", "Crawford", "Prodoehl", 
"Mofar", "During", "Hooper", "Hockenbery", "Evich", "Derwin", 
"Hughes", "Galloway", "Evich", "Johnson", "Kennedy", "Pearson", 
"Heaton", "Lindsey", "Cooper", "Berger", "Johnson", "Melville", 
"frazier", "Williams", "Rohrer", "Brown", "Sirleaf", "Babylon", 
"Goslee", "Massey Jr.", "Owens", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Taylor", 
"Johnson", "Ekop", "Jones", "Zanoni", "Ibezim", "Tregoning", 
"Marshall", "McDonald", "Britton", "Arneson", "Melville"), SCHOOL = c("Gwynn Park", 
"Woodlawn High", "Meade High", "Howard", "Kenwood", "Gwynn Park", 
"Meade High", "Westminster", "Eleanor Roosevelt", "Gwynn Park", 
"Howard", "Middletown", "Middletown", "Middletown", "St Charles", 
"Gwynn Park", "Middletown", "St Charles", "Northwestern PG", 
"Meade High", "Eastern Tech", "Gwynn Park", "Meade High", "Middletown", 
"Middletown", "North Carroll", "Western Tech", "Annapolis", "Liberty", 
"Gwynn park", "Seneca Valley", "Westminster", "Gwynn Park", "St Charles", 
"Catonsville", "St Charles", "St Charles", "Tuscarora", "Gwynn Park", 
"Long Reach", "Middletown", "Linganore", "Gaithersburg", "Linganore", 
"Silver Oak Academy", "Eleanor Roosevelt", "Linganore", "Linganore", 
"North Carroll"), Grade = c("Junior", "Senior", "Sophomore", 
"Junior", "Junior", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Sophomore", "Junior", 
"Senior", "Junior", "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Sophomore", "Sophomore", 
"Sophomore", "Sophomore", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Junior", "Sophomore", 
"Sophomore", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Junior", "Junior", "Sophomore", 
"Junior", "Sophomore", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Freshman", "Junior", 
"Sophomore", "Junior", "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Sophomore", 
"Junior", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior", "Junior", "Junior", 
"Junior", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Junior", "Junior"), POSITION = c("CB", 
"WR", "WR,CB", "WR,CB", "RB", "CB", "WR,CB", "WR,CB", "RB,LB", 
"WR,CB", "WR,S", "RB", "QB", "RB,S", "WR,S", "RB", "CB", "Skills", 
"WR", "WR,CB", "G", "S", "RB", "CB", "WR", "LB", "RB", "QB", 
"Skills", "S", "RB", "WR.LB", "CB", "LB", "WR", "QB", "QB", "Skills", 
"QB", "Skills", "S", "FB,LB", "S", "WR", "WR", "Skills", "Dl", 
"CB", "RB"), WEIGHT = c(137, 163, 153, 173, 179, 130, 145, 164, 
205, 140, 167, 172, 167, 169, 142, 143, 173, 133, 185, 141, 162, 
168, 172.4, 143, 192, 141, 156, 179, 129, 169, 195, 158, 151, 
160, 157, 148, 148, 160, 174, 172, 173, 171, 161, 150, 175, 192, 
207, 152, 133), FORTY = c(4.45, 4.72, 4.69, 4.66, 4.59, 4.79, 
4.69, 4.8, 4.66, 4.61, 4.65, 4.97, 4.87, 4.75, 4.73, 4.6, 5.02, 
5.07, 4.93, 4.75, 4.87, 4.75, 4.87, 5.16, 4.97, 4.83, 4.83, 4.63, 
4.56, 4.95, 4.91, 4.99, 4.68, 4.72, 4.76, 5.09, 5.09, 4.95, 4.98, 
4.99, 4.75, 4.91, 4.85, 4.97, 4.68, 4.84, 5.19, 4.87, 4.94), 
    BROAD = c(112, 106, 94, 106, 105, 95, 112, 106, 106, 116, 
    117, 96, 111, 118, 110, 97, 104, 96, 106, 111, 101, 107, 
    98, 98, 104, 90, 97, 102, 106, 107, 107, 98, 108, 106, 95, 
    94, 94, 102, 113, 110, 116, 102, 109, 108, 112, 104, 98, 
    103, 88), BENCH = c(3, 6, 0, 13, 12, 0, 0, 1, 20, 0, 6, 12, 
    14, 0, 0, 4, 11, 0, 6, 1, 2, 7, 9, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 
    16, 6, 7, 16, 11, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 9, 18, 10, 0, 0, 11, 13, 
    13, 0),`P. AGILITY`= c(3.91, 4.01, 4.06, 4.06, 4.07, 4.12, 
    4.12, 4.12, 4.12, 4.13, 4.13, 4.14, 4.15, 4.18, 4.19, 4.19, 
    4.21, 4.22, 4.23, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.27, 4.28, 
    4.28, 4.28, 4.28, 4.28, 4.28, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 4.3, 4.31, 
    4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.32, 4.34, 4.34, 4.34, 
    4.34, 4.34, 4.35)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Well, there are a few problems here. You can only use reactives value in a reactive context. You will need to make `DF` reactive. Then you will also need to get the values from reactive values using parenthesis. So if you want the value of `x1` you need `x1()`. And then i'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `*` multiply but I think you want that inside the `mutate()` call, not outside. This is what's giving the specific error. You seem to be new to Shiny. Maybe check out the [videos on reactivity from the Shiny developer conference](https://rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/)

Comment: Yes I am very new and trying to learn thank you for your help. That is a great resource!

Comment: I am trying to multiply the generated z score from scale by the user input.  Does that make sense?  such that `Forty_zscore * input$Weight1_Variable`  and then also `Bench_zscore * input$Variable2_Weight` and then sum those two adjusted z scores together.